# How do I increase the pixel density in Qpixmap?

Tags: qt, qpainter, qimage, qpixmap

I want to increase pixel density per unit area on every zoom operation in 'QPixmap'.
To increasing pixel density I create pixmap  on every zoom according to the rectangle get from sceneboundingrect() but I think it does not increase the pixel density

Answer (score 1):

The `QPixmap` is a raster image, that means a finite amount of pixels, making it bigger will not make it clearer (as it does on CSI).

You will need a considerably bigger / larger resolution image to begin with, then you will downsample it when you render it "un-zoomed" and the more you zoom in the closer you render it to its original size.